# Retrieve the field values from a MarkLogic search

Tags: marklogic

I have an XQuery FLOWR search in MarkLogic like the below which returns paginated matching documents in a collection ordered based on a field

```
let $options := 
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <transform-results apply="raw"/>
    <additional-query> 
      {cts:collection-query("http://example.com/myCollectionName")} 
    </additional-query>
    <sort-order direction="descending" >
      <field name="myCustomFieldA" />
    </sort-order>
     <debug>true</debug> 
  </options>

for $searchResults in search:search("someQuery", $options, 1, 10)
return $searchResults
```

I have several custom fields setup on the documents with coresponding field range indexes and I would like to retrieve the values in the fields for the matching documents, rather than the document itself. Something like the following?

```
for $searchResults in search:search("someQuery", $options, 1, 10)
return get-field-values($searchResults, ("myCustomFieldA", "myCustomFieldB"))
```

How would I return these field values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example suggests that you want the results paginated and sorted by a certain range index.

[cts:field-values()](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:field-values) can be used in your iteration with the document URI as a part of a document-query passed to the 4th parameter(query parameter).

However, you may find [cts:value-co-occurences](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:value-co-occurrences) to be useful.

Comment: The problem here is that `cts:field-values` seems to throw an error if myCustomFieldA and myCustomFieldB are different types. I think to actually achieve the output i want would requre one call to cts:field-values per field in question, by which time it is probably easier just to get the raw document and transform that.

Comment: If all you want in the end is content from an index(as in your sample), then retrieving the document and transforming it likely has much more overhead.  compared to two calls for cts:field-values(). See also the answer from ehennum related to search:values() - - which likely uses the cts:xxx-values functions under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

The Search API does support extracting portions of documents using XPaths, which may get close to what you want:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/query-options#id_37692

If you want to return the actual documents, you may find the search:resolve-nodes() function is more useful than search:search() with transform raw:

http://docs.marklogic.com/search:resolve-nodes

Finally, if your fields have range index, search:values() can construct tuples based on co-occurrence in your documents, which should be faster than retrieving documents because the values are retrieved from indexes:

http://docs.marklogic.com/search:values

Comment: Extract-document-data does look like it could do what i want. I am actually using a param to swap between transform raw and snippet view but resolve-nodes does look useful when just using search to grab docs. Just seems weird to me that i can order results based on a field just by name, but not include the value used for that sort in the result set easily.